# Dynamic rows in Crystal report letter template

Tags: crystal-reports

I got a requirement like, in the text object letter template there is a table, and if no values rows should disappear, and below text needs to come upwards accordingly.
Is it possible?

[enter image description here][1]

Comment: Did you try to add an image? It didn't come through

Answer (score 0):

If you feed the table rows from data records (detail section) or Group data (e.g. Group footer), that would happen automatically. No data = no section.

If you feed the table rows from some other logic, you can place each table row in a different section (e.g. GF1a, GF1b, ...) and use a suppress expression in the section property to dynamically suppress based on your logic.

Alternatively, there's at least one 3rd-party tool (see list [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#desktopsched)) that can feed data from a Crystal report into MS Word template document. That tool can indeed expand/remove table rows based on data in the report. The document can then be printed or saved as dynamically named Word or PDF files.